# No string printed into the file

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I am creating a file called jfv.properties and I want to write a simple string into the file. In this the file is getting created the string is not getting printed. Is there problem in the below code ? I have run in the debug mode, there are no exceptions thrown.

```
    File file = new File(filePath,"jfv.properties");
    FileOutputStream fo = null;
    try {
        fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
        PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo);
        p.println("some string");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (SecurityException s){
        s.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(fo != null ){
        try {
            fo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Java 6 or Java 7+?

Comment: the original version of the code posted worked for me because it did contain the "p.close();" but I note it was edited to stop it from working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrintWriter` is not flushed. Use

```
p.println("some string");
p.flush();
```

or use `autoFlush`

```
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo, true);
p.println("some string");
```

or just `close` it.

`autoFlush` works for `println`, `printf` and `format`. See the javadoc of [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

**Details**

The `PrintWriter` can be constructed either with another `Writer`, a `File` or filename or an `OutputStream`. In case of instantiating it using an `OutputStream` the javadoc says:

> public PrintWriter(OutputStream out)
>
> Creates a new PrintWriter, without automatic line flushing, from an existing OutputStream. This convenience constructor creates the necessary intermediate **OutputStreamWriter**, which will convert characters into bytes using the default character encoding.

and the javadoc of [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream)) says:

> ... The resulting bytes are accumulated in a buffer before being written to the underlying output stream. ...

**EDIT**

So your code

```
fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo);
```

will lead to this stream model

```
+-------------+           +--------------------+          +------------------+
| PrintWriter | --------> | OutputStreamWriter | -------> | FileOutputStream |
+-------------+           +--------------------+          +------------------+
```

Therefore a `println` will not directly write the string to the `FileOutputStream`

```
p.println("some string")
  +-> outputStreamWriter.write("some string")
      +--> write to internal buffer (as bytes)

p.flush();
  +-> outputStreamWriter.flush();
      +--> internal buffer flush
         +--> fileOutputStream.write(bytes)
```

Comment: PrinterWriter will do the job. For every run, we are closing the stream, atleast trying to (Something I have missed). Why would we want to run it for every fresh run ?

Comment: @JeevanVarughese In your case you could also just close the `PrintWriter` which will lead to the same result. But you wondered `No string printed into the file` and the reason is because `PrintWriter` has not written the bytes to the `FileOutputStream` yet - it has not been flushed yet. Of course closing a `PrintWriter` flushes it too.

Comment: Thanks !! That helps. Lemme give a quick try... somehow missed that concept ! Thanks !

Comment: @JeevanVarughese I updated the answer in order to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

Better if you include `p.close()` in the `finally`

```
 File file = new File(filePath,"jfv.properties");
        FileOutputStream fo = null;
        try {
            fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo);
            p.println("some string");


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (SecurityException s){
            s.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
    p.close();
if(fo != null ){
            try {
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: This was the actual problem. I had closed the file stream, but missed closing the printwriter.

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File(filePath, "jfv.properties");
        FileOutputStream fo = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fo = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(fo);
            p.println("some string");
            //change it 
            fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("some string");
            bw.flush();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException s) {
            s.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fo != null) {
                    fo.close();
                }
                if (fw != null) {
                    fw.close();
                }
                if (bw != null) {
                    bw.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Catching `Exception` is a bad idea; it will also catch all unchecked exceptions (`RuntimeException` extends `Exception`).

Comment: Not sure about the importance of flush when we are running it in a single thread once

Comment: @JeevanVarughese This might help you! http://stackoverflow.com/a/13185166/2956066