# Java files(sending the string as name of the file)

Tags: java, file

I want to take some information from a document inside the project text_d.txt.

Now I send "text_d.txt" through a string s2.The file already exists(text_d.txt) but the output file s3,doesn't show anything(empty).
The question is: Why it doesn't show anything. Did I write anything wrong?

dict.txt

```
da yes
```

profesor teacher

invata learns

java java

zece ten

programare programming

noteaza rates

primeste gets

student student

and text_d.txt

```
   Student invata programare 
java. Profesor noteaza 
student. Nero primeste zece.
```

This method is used by the file-writing code:

```
   public String getTtoD(String _wordtotranslate,String s)throws Throwable

    {
      FileInputStream _dict=new FileInputStream(s);
      BufferedReader _read=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_dict));
      String _line=_read.readLine();
      char c;
      int sem=0;
      for(int i=0;i<_wordtotranslate.length();i++)
      {
          c=_wordtotranslate.charAt(i);
          if(c>='A' && c<='Z')
              sem=1;

      }
      _wordtotranslate=_wordtotranslate.toLowerCase();
      while(_line!=null)

      {
         String [] _v=_line.split(" ");
         if(_wordtotranslate.equals(_v[1]))
         {
             if(sem==1)
                  {_v[0]=_v[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+_v[0].substring(1);
                  return _v[0];
                  }

             return _v[0];
         }

         _line=_read.readLine();
      }
     _read.close();
     if(sem==1)return             _wordtotranslate=_wordtotranslate.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+_wordtotranslate.substring(1);
     return _wordtotranslate;

    }
```

### This is the code where the file is written:

```
       if(dan==1)
     {
      File f=new File(s3);
      f.createNewFile();
      FileInputStream _inputfile=new FileInputStream(s2);
      BufferedReader _readfile=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_inputfile));
      String _str=_readfile.readLine();
      FileWriter _filewrite=new FileWriter(f);
      BufferedWriter _buffwrt=new BufferedWriter(_filewrite);
      while(_str!=null)
      {
            while (_str != null) {
                String[] _vect = _str.split(" ");
                if(_vect.length>4)throw new WrongSyntax();
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < _vect.length; i++) {
                    if (_vect[i].contains(".")) {
                         _vect[i]=removeCharAt(_vect[i],_vect[i].indexOf("."));
                        _buffwrt.write(getDtoT(_vect[i],s4) + ".");

                    }

                    else
                        _buffwrt.write(getDtoT(_vect[i],s4) + " ");
                    _buffwrt.flush();
                }
                _buffwrt.flush();
                _str =_readfile.readLine();

            }
            _buffwrt.close();
      }
```

Comment: Did you flush the buffer?

Comment: [Use `java.nio.files`](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Using_the_java.nio.file_API), please. And show the code where you write to the file as well

Comment: If that's all your code, you need to close your streams, which flushes the buffers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams

Comment: @Compass  used the flush

Comment: @fge i didn't write it,it is written already(text file)

Comment: Then what is the `BufferedWriter` for?

Comment: @fge i have a 2 files already written(with text in them) represented as s4("dict.txt") and s2("text.txt"),and i want to write in a third file s3,which i create

Comment: Can you add the content of the text_d.txt file to your question? Also, the code of `getDtoT` and `removeCharAt`.

Comment: OK, let me get something clear first; each time you invoke your method you open the three files? That seems like a waste

Comment: @fge yes,well openning 2 and creating the third..The problem is i am not familiar in java with files.I have to send through String [] args(of the main method) string arguments for the text files,thus i am using them in this method