# NewLines missing while writing to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

I'm trying to read txt file and pass data from it using Sockets, but looks like I'm missing newlines while writing to outputstream.

My txt file is:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "New York",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  }
}
```

---

ByteArrayOutputStream:

> {  "firstName": "John",  "lastName": "Smith",  "isAlive":
>   true,  "age": 25,  "address": {%    "streetAddress": "21 2nd
>   Street",    "city": "New York",    "state": "NY",
>   "postalCode": "10021-3100"  }}

---

Scaner:
[image]

```
private byte[] readFile(String path) throws IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(baos);

    File file = new File(path);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        out.writeUTF(scanner.nextLine());
    }

    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    return bytes;
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Helped me with new lines, but I still get some invalid characters in `baos`

```
System.out.println(new String(baos.toByteArray()));
```

[image]

Comment: `nextLine()` reads a line without the new line character

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes-java.nio.file.Path-, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.io.OutputStream-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `.flush()` helped me to clear invalid characters...

```
private byte[] readFile(String path) throws IOException {

    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    File file = new File(path);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        out.writeUTF(scanner.nextLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    byte[] bytes = out.toByteArray();
    out.flush();
    return bytes;
}
```

[What is the purpose of flush() in Java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the code using below

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        out.writeUTF(scanner.nextLine()+"\n");
    }
```

Comment: The new line character isn't \n on every system so it's better to use System.getProperty("line.separator")