# OutputStreamWriter not saving data when activity stopped

Tags: android, save, local-storage, storage, outputstream

In my app the user goes to different activities to buy upgrades and I want it so that if they close the app on that activity their stuff will be saved.

This is my way of saving that information:

```
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    writeCounttofile();
    writeSingletofile();
    writeAddtofile();
}

public void writeCounttofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("countvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(countervalue));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private int readCountFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int countervalue = 0;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("countvalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            countervalue = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //here you catch and watch the problem
        Log.e("MyActivity", "cant parse string: " + result);
    }
    return countervalue;
}

public void writeAddtofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("addvalue.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(Add));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private int readAddFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int add = 0;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("addvalue.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            add = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //here you catch and watch the problem
        Log.e("MyActivity", "cant parse string: " + result);
    }
    return add;
}

public void writeSingletofile() {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("single.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(String.valueOf(Singleadd));
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", e.toString());
    }
}


private int readSingleFromFile() {

    String result = "";
    int single = 1;
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("single.txt");

        if (inputStream != null) {

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String tempString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((tempString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                stringBuilder.append(tempString);

            }

            inputStream.close();

            result = stringBuilder.toString();
            single = Integer.parseInt(result);

        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.v("MyActivity", "File not found" + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //here you catch and watch the problem
        Log.e("MyActivity", "cant parse string: " + result);
    }
    return single;
}
```

And when they return to the app on the main activity I called all the read methods and have the values of the app equal those upgrades, but for some reason it doesn't work. When I close the app from the main activity it saves all the information fine, which is why I just copied the methods from the main activity to my other activities. Is this whats wrong?

Please and Thank You.

Comment: It's always a good idea to flush your output stream after writing something into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you the onStop method does  not allow you to perform some operations, so to solve it call those methods from the onPause method