# Java OutputStream buffer size

Tags: java, buffer, httpurlconnection, outputstream, flush

The `OutputStream` in Java has a method named `flush()`. Based on its documentation:

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out.

How can I understand how much of a multi-byte capacity this buffer is?

---

Extra note: I've got my own `OutputStream` from an `HttpURLConnection` `getOutputStream()` method.

Comment: What is a "multi-byte capacity"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the kind of **OutputStream** you're using.

Let's start with the basics, by analyzing what flush of OutputStream proposes as a contract:

> public void flush()
>              throws IOException
>
> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an
>   indication that, if **any bytes previously written have been buffered by
>   the implementation of the output stream**, such bytes should immediately
>   be written to their intended destination.
>
> If the intended destination of this *stream is an abstraction provided
>   by the underlying operating system*, for example a file, then flushing
>   the stream guarantees only that **bytes previously written to the stream
>   are passed to the operating system for writing**; it does not guarantee
>   that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk
>   drive.
>
> The flush method of **OutputStream** does nothing.

And if you see the flush method of OutputStream, it actually does nothing:

```
public void flush() throws IOException {
}
```

The idea is that the implementation that is decorating an OutputStream will have to deal with its flush and then cascade it to other OutputStreams until it reaches the OS if that is the case.

So it does something! By means of whoever is implementing it. The concrete classes will override flush to do something like moving data to disk or sending it over the network (your case).

If you check out the flush of a **BufferedOutputStream**:

```
/**
 * Flushes this buffered output stream. This forces any buffered
 * output bytes to be written out to the underlying output stream.
 *
 * @exception  IOException  if an I/O error occurs.
 * @see        java.io.FilterOutputStream#out
 */
public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
    flushBuffer();
    out.flush();
}

/** Flush the internal buffer */
private void flushBuffer() throws IOException {
    if (count > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, count);
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

You may see that it's writing the contents of its own buffer to the wrapped OutputStream. And you can see the default size of its buffer (or you could change it), see its constructors:

```
/**
 * The internal buffer where data is stored.
 */
protected byte buf[];

/**
 * Creates a new buffered output stream to write data to the
 * specified underlying output stream.
 *
 * @param   out   the underlying output stream.
 */
public BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out) {
    this(out, 8192);
}

/**
 * Creates a new buffered output stream to write data to the
 * specified underlying output stream with the specified buffer
 * size.
 *
 * @param   out    the underlying output stream.
 * @param   size   the buffer size.
 * @exception IllegalArgumentException if size &lt;= 0.
 */
public BufferedOutputStream(OutputStream out, int size) {
    super(out);
    if (size <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Buffer size <= 0");
    }
    buf = new byte[size];
}
```

So, the default size of the **BufferedInputStream** buffer is 8192 bytes.

Now that you got the gist, check out the code the **OutputStream** that is being used for you in your **HttpURLConnection** to familiarize yourself with its buffer (if it has one).

In your java journey, you may end up with some native code that delegates the action of flushing to the OS. In that case you may have to check if your OS is working with some buffer and what is its size when dealing with IO. I know that this part of the answer may sound way to broad, but that is the reality of it. You need to know what you're working with in order to get the idea of what is behind it.

Check out this question:
[What is the purpose of flush() in Java streams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340106/what-is-the-purpose-of-flush-in-java-streams)

And this article:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/perftuning-137844.html

cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed description. I will check the implementation of the `OutputStream` that is being used in `HttpURLConnection` and will publish the result here if I found something useful.