# How to generate a unique numeric ID and keep count in java?

Tags: java, arrays, excel, random, unique

I'm working on a Java robot that copies the information from an excel file and pastes it on a program to create a username. I get everything I need from the excel file, except an ID number.

I'm trying to generate a unique numeric-only ID (So UUID won't work). It has to be 6 digits long, thus, its range is between 100,000 and 999,999. This is what I've got so far:

```
public void genID() {
    ArrayList<Integer> casillero = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 100000; i < 1000000; i++) {
        casillero.add(new Integer(i));
    } Collections.shuffle(casillero);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("El nuevo ID de casillero es: I" + casillero.get(i));
    }
}
```

This generates a 6 digit number and that's great. But how do I make sure that this number hasn't and won't be generated next time I run my java program? Thank you!

Comment: Where do you store these numbers or the objects that hold these numbers? casillero, right? Check if it already exists first.

Comment: You need to _persist_ the data somewhere (text file, database etc.).

Comment: Currently I'm not storing the existing numbers anywhere. I will try that, thank you.

Comment: It depends on your specific env. For example, you would concatenate a part of IP address and process ID and some part of current time. But in general case, only 6 decimal num positions may lead to very possible collision. So, yes, think about some shared and persist counter like RMDBS's sequence/auto-increment or something like that

Comment: Thank you everyone for the suggestions! Those are really smart solutions, I will try to work them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible for the JVM to remember any values from its previous run-time (excluding static values compiled in the code itself). Because if this, you have to write your program to save important data **at run-time**, otherwise it will be lost when the last thread terminates. Java supports a multitude of [`InputStreams`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) and [`OutputStreams`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) which make way for an entire world of possibilities, including file reading and writing.

The basic method of writing a file  is using a [`FileOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), which   writes raw bytes to a given file. There are some objects like the [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) which automatically get the  bytes of the given string (or parsed  string if an object is passed) and write them to the output stream.

---

You  need to save your IDs to a file before your program terminates, and read the file every time the `genID()` method is invoked. Once you have read the file, you can use a simple a loop to check the generated ID list for  any existing values. Consider this example:

```
public void genID() {
    ArrayList<Integer> casillero = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 100000; i < 1000000; i++) {
        casillero.add(new Integer(i));
    } Collections.shuffle(casillero);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        System.out.println("El nuevo ID de casillero es: I" + casillero.get(i));
    }

    try {
        getUsedIDS().forEach(i -> {
            /*
             * Iterate through the existing IDs
             * and make sure that casillero does
             * not contain any of them.
             */
            if(casillero.contains(i)) casillero.remove(i);
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public List<Integer> getUsedIDS() throws IOException {
    //The file which you saved the IDs to.
    File file = new File("IDs.txt");
    //Return all the values in the file.
    return Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()).stream().mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
public void saveIDs(List<Integer> IDs) throws FileNotFoundException {
    /*
     * Create a PrintStream that writes into a 
     * FileOutputStream which in turn writes to your file.
     * Because 'true' was passed to the constructor, this
     * stream will append to the file.
     */
    PrintStream s = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("IDs.txt"), true));
    //Print every element in the IDs list.
    IDs.forEach(s::println);
    /*
     * Read more about flush here:
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/2340125/5645656
     */
    s.flush();
    /*
     * Close the stream to prevent a resource leak.
     */
    s.close();
}
```

Comment: Well, it really has nothing to do with garbage collection.

Comment: @JamesKPolk please explain. I've always believed it was a result of garbage collection.

Comment: Garbage collection is how the JVM recycles the memory used by discarded and unreachable objects *during* the execution of a Java program.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I will read about FileOutputStream and PrintStream and go on from there. Have a nice day!